# Java and Database Query?

Tags: java, database, derby

Using Derby as my data base driver and tying to execute SQL query through java,
there was a error that was encounter, when tried to execute this particular query

```
stmt.executeQuery("insert into " + "TEST " + "values (" + dataTimeRev + ", " 
                                  + dataType + "," + obj + ")" );
```

Here dataTimeRev, dataType and obj are variables with data.

The error that was stated was like this

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: VALUES clause must contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed.
```

Comment: Is it because you did not list the names of the columns into which you are inserting the values? `insert into test(colA,colB) values(1,2)`

Comment: Does your TEST has only three fields? Are those strings? If so, it should be in single quotes.

Comment: Have updated the question, sorry for the wrong post

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the values in single quotes?

Comment: Test has been declared in this fashion, Time(double), DataType (varchar (32)), Data (BLOB) of size 60,000

Comment: Well the syntax is dependent on which sql you are using, so which one is it, MYSQL? But like paulsm4 said, the error should not be happening. I would say check to make sure something is in the actual variables. From the error, I am gathering that it might possibly be null. Manish Sharma also makes a good point, it looks like you are missing the single quotes around the non digit variables, unless you have that included in the variables.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight NO! INSERT INTO can work without specifying the column name :)

Comment: @ Andy Apache Derby is the one that's in use, 10.2 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the column data type is VARCHAR you will have to pass the value in qoutes like `'value'` for that you should do as below

```
String query = "insert into TEST values('"+dataTimeRev+"', '"+dataType+"','"+obj+"')";
stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that dataTimeRev, dataType and obj are not null and not blank.
2. I am not sure if Derby follows SQL syntax. But if the values are of type varchar, then it should be enclosed in single quotes ('). For example:

> stmt.executeQuery("insert into " + "TEST " + "values ('" + dataTimeRev + " ', ' " 
>                                     + dataType + " ',' " + obj + " ')" );

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stmt.executeQuery("insert into TEST values ('" + dataTimeRev + "', "'+ dataType + "',"' + obj + "')" );
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes of this error is trying to insert a Type that isn't a String (Date, Double, Integer e.t.c, surrounded by the single quotation mark `''`
For example my table was declared like this:

```
 String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE PRODUCT"+ "(product_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)," +
                "product_name CHAR(80), "+
                "price DOUBLE," +
                "supplier CHAR(50))";
```

So I was doing:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE, DATE_SUPPLIED, QUANTITY, SUPPLIER) VALUES " +
        "('" + productName + "', " + "'" + price + "', " + "'" + supplier +"')");
```

instead of:

```
 statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE, DATE_SUPPLIED, QUANTITY, SUPPLIER) VALUES " +
        "('" + productName + "', " + price + ", " + "'" + supplier +"')");
```